# Argument not being taken from class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to create a class to make my program easier to make when it hopefully gets bigger. I have class Tilemap, that creates a pygame sprite. I try to call this sprite, then blit it. But when I do so, it claims that it isn't a surface but instead it says it is the Tilemap class. The Error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Desktop Files\Python\Pygame RPG Type Game\RPG TEST 2.py", line 166, in <module>
    main()
  File "F:\Desktop Files\Python\Pygame RPG Type Game\RPG TEST 2.py", line 60, in main
    map_surface.blit(tile_surface,(x*TILE_WIDTH,y*TILE_HEIGHT))
TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not Tilemap
```

The code I am using for all of this is as follows

Code that errors:

```
player = Player(locationPlayer)
    grasstile = Tilemap(locationGrass)
    watertile = Tilemap(locationWater)
    waterbeach = Tilemap(locationBeach)

    TILE_WIDTH = 32
    TILE_HEIGHT = 32


    tilemap = [
                [grasstile, grasstile, grasstile, grasstile, waterbeach, watertile, watertile, watertile, watertile],
                [grasstile, grasstile, grasstile, grasstile, waterbeach, watertile, watertile, watertile, watertile],
                [grasstile, grasstile, grasstile, grasstile, waterbeach, watertile, watertile, watertile, watertile],
                [watertile, watertile, watertile, watertile, watertile, watertile, watertile, watertile, watertile]
            ]

    total_level_width = len(tilemap[0]) * 32
    total_level_height = len(tilemap)*32

    camera = Camera(simple_camera ,total_level_width, total_level_height)


    map_surface = pygame.Surface(( len(tilemap[0])*TILE_WIDTH, len(tilemap)*TILE_HEIGHT))

    for y,row in enumerate(tilemap):
        for x,tile_surface in enumerate(row):
            map_surface.blit(tile_surface,(x*TILE_WIDTH,y*TILE_HEIGHT))

    map_surface = pygame.transform.scale(map_surface, (1200, 800))
```

Class:

```
class Tilemap(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, fileloc):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(fileloc).convert()
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

Thank you for your time in answering this, and please do note I am fairly new to Pygame, and it's code. Thank you again

Comment: And on which line do you get the error? And in the future, if you're asking a question regarding a runtime error like this, please include the *complete* and *unedited* stack-trace in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that you couldn't see the error myself. I posted this at 1AM for me, The full error is now in the post

Answer (score 1):

> `map_surface.blit(tile_surface,(x*TILE_WIDTH,y*TILE_HEIGHT))`

[pygame.Surface.blit](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) takes `pygame.Surface` as the first argument, while you gives `tile_surface`, which is an instance of `Tilemap`.

Comment: Yes, I figured that. But I am wondering how to get the pygame.Surface from Tilemap